# How can I convert Class<Derived> to Class<Base>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a base class with multiple derived classes:

```
class Base { }

class Derived1 : Base { }

class Derived2 : Base { }
```

Then I have a worker class that takes this class as a generic type:

```
class WorkerClass<T> where T : Base, new()
{
    WorkerClass() { }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        T container = new T();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is when I instantiate WorkerClass, I only have the type as a variable. I would like to do this:

```
void DoStuff(Type type)
{
    WorkerClass<Base> worker_class = null;

    if(type == typeof(Derived1))
    {
        worker_class = new WorkerClass<Derived1>();  // compiler error
    }
    else if(type == typeof(Derived2))
    {
        worker_class = new WorkerClass<Derived2>();  // compiler error
    }

    // lots of common code with worker_class
    worker_class.DoStuff();
}
```

But the compiler complains about implicitly casting `WorkerClass<Derived>` to `WorkerClass<Base>`. Explicitly casting gives an error as well. The compiler suggests defining `public static implicit operator WorkerClass<T>(WorkerClass<Derived>)`, but I'm not sure what that code would look like. I could obviously put all the logic inside the if-else, but that seems needlessly repetitive.

Comment: instead of `DoStuff(Type type)` use generic method. `DoStuff<T2>() where T2 : Base, new()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misreading your intent, but I would think you could do something like this using generics with constraints:

```
void DoStuff<T>() where T : Base, new()
{
  WorkerClass<T> worker_class = new WorkerClass<T>();

  // lots of common code with worker_class
  worker_class.DoStuff();
}
```

From there you would simply call, for example:

```
DoStuff<Derived1>();
```

Comment: Accepted as the simplest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I made several corrections to your code to get it to work. Your `WorkerClass<T>` needs to inherit from the `Base` class as well and you may need to override the `DoStuff` call in your super class if you that code to be executed instead of the `DoStuff` method in the `Base` class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class Base
    {
        public virtual void DoStuff(){}
    }

    public class Derived1 : Base
    {
        public virtual void DoStuff(){}
    }

    public class Derived2 : Base
    {
        public virtual void DoStuff(){}
    }

    public class WorkerClass<T> : Base where T : Base,new()
    {
        public WorkerClass() { }

        public override void DoStuff()
        {
            T container = new T();
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), but it is only supported on interfaces and delegates. Try introducing the interface `IWorkerClass<out T>`. The `out` keyword marks the template type `T` as covariant.

```
interface IWorkerClass<out T> 
{
    void DoStuff();
}

class WorkerClass<T> : IWorkerClass<T> where T : Base, new() 
{ 
    public void DoStuff() { }
}
```

Then use the interface instead of the class in your code example:

```
void DoStuff(Type type)
{
    IWorkerClass<Base> worker_class = null;

    if(type == typeof(Derived1))
    {
        worker_class = new WorkerClass<Derived1>();  // NO compiler error
    }
    else if(type == typeof(Derived2))
    {
        worker_class = new WorkerClass<Derived2>();  // NO compiler error
    }

    // lots of common code with worker_class
    worker_class.DoStuff();
}
```